# How to safely create unique relations with Entity Framework in multi process environment?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, worker-process

I have following code that is executed in web garden, (multiple ASP.NET worker processes) to achieve good performance. Everything is fine except this code fragment.

There is unique index on UserTaskRelation and here is my code...

```
// There is Unique Index for TaskID and UserID
var t = db.UserTaskRelations.FirstOrDefault(
            x=> x.TaskID == taskID 
                && x.UserID == userID);
if(t==null){
    t = new UserTaskRelation { TaskID=taskID, UserID = userID };
    db.UserTaskRelations.AddObject(t);
}
t.LastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
db.SaveChanges();
```

This code fails on last line when same user hits refresh page for the same task, while previous request was still in queue, and one of the request fails.

Since this is executed in multi process environment, lock does not help also locking with mutex does not help as we have multiple web servers performing same.

I wrapped everything up in Transaction like this...

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(
          TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{

    // all of above code here...

    scope.Complete();
}
```

This still does not help... out of 100 operations I see 1-5% of them fail. Is there anyway to safely insert this, like stored procedure etc?

I am currently doing a dirty workaround...

```
1. Try Logic
2. Catch Exception
3. Try Get Logic (assuming it exists)
```

But I do not like to write Catching Exception as part of logic.